# how to animate using jquery after a function has finished - make the second function wait?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple jQuery code which swaps two images by hiding one and displaying the other, I'm seeking to swap the images using a fade in fade out effect, but since the two images aren't lying on top of each other I cant simply fade the top image resulting on showing the bottom one, 
I want to fade the first image then set the css display property to none then show the second image with 0 opacity and gradually set the second images opacity to 100. But when I add the code which fades the images, it doesn't work and the display none doesn't wait for the fade to finish. How can I make the functions wait for the one before to finish?

```
$('.thumbs').hover(
        function() {
           console.info('in');
           $(this).children('.first').css('display','none'); 
           $(this).children('.second').css('display','block')
        },
        function() {
           console.info('out');
           $(this).children('.second').css('display','none'); 
           $(this).children('.first').css('display','block')
         }
);
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class='thumbs'>
            <div class='first'><?php the_post_thumbnail()?></div>
            <div class='second'><?php MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');?></div>
                 </div>
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML as well? Also, where's the code that gradually changes the opacity? The code you've posted just hides/shows the divs instantaneously.

Comment: @Osiris: I added the html and as for the opacity change It's the same code with only $(this).children('.first').css('opacity','0'); added before the display:none part and then $(this).children('.second').css('opacity','100') after the display block keeping in mind that the second images opacity is set to 0 at first.

Answer (score 3):

**1)** `delay()` method allows us to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. 
http://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
$( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```

**2)** use `callbacks`

```
$("#divId1").animate({opacity:.1},1000,function(){
    $("#divId2").animate({opacity:.1},1000);    
});​
```

Comment: using callback functions sound the right way to go but the problem is that I want to use $(this).children('.first') and it seems once inside the call back function the ($this) statement doesn't refer to the wrapper in the it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('out');
    $(this).children('.second').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).children('.first').css('display', 'block');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested but this should do the job:

```
$('.thumbs').hover(
    function(){
       var $that = $(this);
       $(this).children('.first').fadeOut(1000, function(){
           $(this).css('display','none');
           $that.children('.second').fadeIn(500);
       });
    }
    ,
   function(){
       var $that = $(this);
       $(this).children('.second').fadeOut(1000, function(){
           $(this).css('display','none');
           $that.children('.first').fadeIn(500);
       });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.thumbs').hover(
        function() {
           var second = $(this).children('.second');
           $(this).children('.first').fadeOut(1000, function(){
              second.fadeIn(1000,function(){});
           }); 
        },
        function() {
           var first= $(this).children('.first');
           $(this).children('.second').fadeOut(1000, function(){
              first.fadeIn(1000,function(){});
           }); 
         }
);
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veN3E/)

Comment: I tried the code, but I don't know why it doesn't fade and only disappears and reappears,

Comment: @Farzan check the fiddle example